# Cannot cast View to <fragment>

Tags: android, fragment

In my xml I have the following code:

```
    <fragment android:name="somepackage.Fragments.ToolbarFragment"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

and in my code I have:

```
private ToolbarFragment toolbarFragment;
toolbarFragment = (ToolbarFragment) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_fragment);
```

I receive the error: "cannot cast android.view.View to somepackage.Fragments.ToolbarFragment"

why is android seeing the fragment as a generic view type instead of as the fragment class that I specified?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are calling `findViewById()`. That is for finding a `View`, such as a widget.

If you want to find a *fragment*, call `findFragmentById()` on your `FragmentManager`, which you get by calling `getFragmentManager()` (native fragments) or `getSupportFragmentManager()` (fragments backport from `support-v4` or `support-v13`) on your activity.

Answer (score 3):

Try this way

```
somepackage.Fragments.ToolbarFragment  toolbarFragment = (somepackage.Fragments.ToolbarFragment) findFragmentById(R.id.toolbar_fragment);
```